# How to reference a BufferReader variable outside of try/catch block

Tags: java, android, try-catch, bufferedreader

I'm trying to read a csv file in res/raw/ into a SQLite database. Here is my function:

```
public void updateDatabase(Context context, SQLiteDatabase database) {

    InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.teamlist);
    try {
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ioe) {
        Log.e("ERROR", "Could not load " + ioe);
    }

    String line = "";

    database.beginTransaction();
    try {
        while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            // read each line from CSV file into a database

        }
    } catch (IOException ioe){
        Log.e("ERROR", "Could not load " + ioe);
    }
    database.setTransactionSuccessful();
    database.endTransaction();
}
```

But I get the error "Cannot resolve symbol 'buffer'" in the while loop. How do I reference the BufferReader outside the try function? I tried initializing the buffer reader outside the try block using "null", but that caused my app to crash. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't write code like this. A more correct way to write it would be:

```
public void updateDatabase(Context context, SQLiteDatabase database) {

    try (InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.teamlist);
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));) {

        String line;
        database.beginTransaction();
        while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            // read each line from CSV file into a database

        }
        database.setTransactionSuccessful();
        database.endTransaction();
    } catch (IOException ioe){
        Log.e("ERROR", "Could not load " + ioe);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ioe) {
        Log.e("ERROR", "Could not load " + ioe);
    }
}
```

In summary, code that depends on the success of code that is in a prior `try` block should be inside that `try` block. Don't write strings of `try/catch` statements like you did.

Note that this also cures a resource leak on the input stream, and that the `line` variable does not need to be initialized.

Comment: Makes sense. I'll change it and give it a shot. Thanks for the advice!